# Replacing dictionary values as a ratio of total values in the dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, math

My code example as below

```
 dict1 = {'c': 2, 'p': 1.0}
```

Want to alter values of the dict to represent a ratio of itself out of the total values

```
dict1 = {'c': 0.6666666666666666, 'p': 0.3333333333333333}
```

Comment: not a python expert but you can get the array of values, sum them, then divide each entry (value) by the sum you calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'c': 2, 'p': 1.0}                                                      
>>> d1 = { k: d[k]/sum(d[k] for k in d) for k in d }
>>> d1
{'c': 0.6666666666666666, 'p': 0.3333333333333333}
>>>
```

Note: avoid to use `dict` as variable name, it's a [python's builtin](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Explanation of the one-liner:

- `d1 = {}` -> d1 is a dictionary
- `d1 = { k: ... for k in d}` -> all keys of `d1` are the ones of `d`
- `sum(d[k] for k in d)` -> calculate the sum of all values of d

So, the `...` part above contains `d[k]/sum(d[k] for k in d)`: this makes the quotient of the value matching the key `k` by the sum of all values of d.

EDIT: as alykhank suggested in comment, it's possible to do this in two lines and save execution time by not recomputing the sum at each iteration.

```
>>> total = sum(d.values())
>>> d2 = {k: d[k]/total for k in d}
>>> d2
{'c': 0.6666666666666666, 'p': 0.3333333333333333}
>>>
```

Comment: I would suggest saving the total to avoid recalculating it in each iteration: `total = sum(d.values())` then `d1 = {k: d[k]/total for k in d}`.